# error while refreshing the data in JTable using TableModel

Tags: java, sql, swing

I am trying to refresh the data from a JTable.

This method select the data from database:

```
public Object[][] getData() {
    Object[][] data = new Object[15][10];
    try {

        String query = "SELECT * from emailApp";
        rs = st.executeQuery(query);


        int i = 0;
        while (rs.next()) {
            int id = rs.getInt("id");
            int priority = rs.getInt("priority");
            String sender = rs.getString("sender");
            String recipient = rs.getString("recipient");
            String labelDb = rs.getString("label");
            String subject = rs.getString("subject");
            String message = rs.getString("message");


            data[i][0] = id;
            data[i][1] = sender;
            data[i][2] = priority;
            data[i][3] = recipient;
            data[i][4] = labelDb;
            data[i][5] = subject;
            data[i][6] = message;
            i++;

            if(i>15) break;

        }

    } catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }

    return data;
}
```

Then I am using this method to refresh the data from the JTable:

```
public void setUpTableData() {
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
DBConnect connect = new DBConnect();
Object[][] data = connect.getData();
Object[] modelData = new Object[15];

model.setRowCount(0);
for(int i = 0; i<15; i++) {
    if(data[i][0] == null) break;
    modelData[0] = data[i][0];
    modelData[1] = data[i][1];
    modelData[2] = data[i][2];
    modelData[3] = data[i][3];
    modelData[4] = data[i][4];
    modelData[5] = data[i][5];
    modelData[6] = data[i][6];

    model.addRow(data);
    }   

model.fireTableDataChanged();
table.setModel(model);
}
```

**Error:** Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.JTable$1 cannot be cast to javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel

and then I am calling this method by pressing a button.
Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong. Thank you!

Comment: Note: `if(i>15)` -> What happens when you reach index 15? Looks out of bounds to me :-)

Comment: Also if you'll like help fixing an "error", it would help us if _we_ also knew what it was.

Comment: What kind of error you are getting ?

Comment: I updated the main post with the error and with the if statements.

Comment: Instead of trying to reuse the existing table model, create a new DefaultTableModel and set to the table. There is no need to call fireTableDataChanged, this is called internally by the DefaultTableModel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, thanks to MadProgrammer, i figured out and solved the problem (In case someone has the same problem)

```
public void refreshData() {
    DBConnect connect = new DBConnect(); 
    Object[][] data = connect.getData(); // collecting the data from DataBase after inserting, updating
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);  // creating a new DefaultTableModel with the new data
    table.setModel(model); // setting the DefaultTableModel to the table - Refreshing the table
}
```